# How do I output rating of teams?

Tags: sql, oracle, rating

I have 2 tables: `team(team_id, name)`, `performance(team_id, stage, place, date)`. Teams should earn points: for 1st place - 10 points, for 2nd 5, for 3rd - 3 points and 1 point for 4-7 places. I need to output the rating of teams.
I think it should be like:

```
SELECT team.name, CASE place
WHEN 1 points + 10
WHEN 2 points + 5
...
```

Expected reasult:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      team.name      |     Points       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Rockers    |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Batmans    |         23       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ...        |         ...      | 
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please, clarify the platform. Some features differ between platforms

Comment: Please edit the question and show example table data and expected output of that data.  WHat does the date have to do with the query logic?  Please be more specific.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Date doesn't metter, its just time when performance has been.

Comment: Please make clear where do you store the previous points.

Comment: @ivangreek I don`t save points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate inside the table `performance` to calculate the total points of each team with conditional aggregation and then join the table `team` to the results and rank the teams with `RANK()` or maybe `DENSE_RANK()` analytical functions:

```
select t.team_id, t.name, 
       coalesce(p.points, 0) points,
       rank() over (order by coalesce(p.points, 0) desc) rnk
from team t left join (
  select team_id,
    sum(
      case
        when place = 1 then 10
        when place = 2 then 5
        when place = 3 then 3
        when place <= 7 then 1
        else 0
      end
    ) points
  from performance 
  group by team_id
) p on p.team_id = t.team_id
```